# Find out the percentage split grouped by currency

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a result set as follows

```
Metal.   Currency.   Quantity
Gold.    USD.        10
Gold.    GBP.        3
Gold.    AUD.        26
```

What I want to return is which currency had the highest percentage and by how much, so I want to say, as an example:

```
"85% of Gold was bought with AUD"
```

So essentially I am totalling up the amounts, 10,3 and 26 to get 39 the code should be along the lines of

```
sum(quantity) / (select total (in this case 39))
```

Im having trouble in returning the percentage for each currency, is there a way to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window funtions:

```
select metal, currency, sum(quantity),
       sum(quantity) * sum(sum(quantity)) over (partition by metal)
from t
group by metal, currency;
```

Comment: what is the reason for sum(sum ?

Comment: @Nonagon . . . To get the overall sum for each `metal`.